# WP7 combo box equivalent

Tags: windows-phone-7, drop-down-menu, odata, listpicker

i am trying to create a dropdown in wp7 such that it will have a text property and a value.

what control will i use and does anyone have an exmaple that shows how to bind it to Odata?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the ListPicker control from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). ListPicker inherits from ItemsControl so any tutorial about binding to a list will help you, but there's an good article [ListPicker for WP7 in depth](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth).